# Restart background SVG animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG set as a background image of an element. The first time the element is displayed, the animation plays correctly.

On subsequent displays (e.g. if a duplicate of the element is injected via JavaScript, or if the background image is removed and added back with CSS/JavaScript), the animation does not start from the beginning. I think this is intended functionality as the image is not considered to have been reloaded by the browser - it uses the in memory version which is already animating.

Here is a demo of this (not mine):
http://www.luigifab.info/public/svg-smil/test.html

There are some associated browser bugs reports for [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843308) and [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177277), but as above I think this is intended functionality.

Is there any way to get my SVG animation to reset/replay whenever the image is displayed?

I'm ideally looking for a solution using just CSS and SVG - else a solution with JavaScript if this is not possible.

Comment: Your SVG images are not showing right..? that is problem uh..?..

Comment: The SVGs are showing, they're just not animating on subsequent displays. If you click the demo link above, then hit 'show' you will see the SVG animate. Click 'hide' then 'show' again and the SVG won't animate.

Comment: Can you show me your Animate code..?

Comment: It's using SVG animation, the code is similar to the SVG used in the demo link above: http://www.luigifab.info/public/svg-smil/error.svg.php

Answer (score 15):

As @netsurfer said, I solved this issue by using an `object`. Here is an example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
```

Every time I dynamically inject the SVG `object` the animation starts from the beginning.

Comment: So you use this `<object>` as background with absolute positioning?

Comment: M V P - worked like a charm 

Answer (score 13):

I think your guess "... as the image is not considered to have been reloaded by the browser - it uses the in memory version which is already animating" is correct, as the SVG file is cached! So without a (real) 'reload' the animation is not triggered (again).

Well, firstly let's have a look at SVG animations. There are two attributes you can use inside an animation element which are used to repeat the animation - see [Repeating Animations](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-animation.html#repeating-animations) and [The ‘animate’ element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement). In your case the animation runs only once (no repetition).

So you would need Javascript to somehow "trigger" the animation.
This is possible in principle (example: [Advanced SVG Animation Techniques](http://web.archive.org/web/20140228202850/http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/advanced-svg-animation-techniques)), but only if the SVG file is part of the DOM, which you can access via Javascript. Therefor you have to include the SVG file as an `<object>`.

As soon as you use a SVG file in an `<img>` tag or as a CSS `background-image` you have no script access to the file.

So the only way I could think of to achieve your goal is to prevent the browser from caching the SVG file (see [How (and how not) to Control Caches](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL)), or to use the SVG file in an `<object>` element so that you can control the animation via Javascript.

BTW: luigifab's answer is not that bad. This is an often used "trick" to force reload of a file/ an image - see [The Cache Trick](http://hivelogic.com/articles/the-cache-trick)

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is to change image URL to force browser reload.

Comment: Change it every time someone visits the page!?

Answer (score 3):

Implementation for luigifab's answer. put some `random things` at the end of the url parameter, this will force browser to think that the resource is a "new resource". [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DG5SS/)

Answer (score 2):

I think in many scenarios `setCurrentTime(0)` is the best solution -- if supported by the browser. Here is an example (assuming you use the `<object>` tag for embedding, of course):

```
let content = document.getElementById("object-id").contentDocument;
let svg = content.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
if(svg.getCurrentTime() > 10)
  svg.setCurrentTime(0);
```

More infos about the relevant API can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me, 
Simply adding and removing "play" class to a div element by adding setTimeout to delay classList.add('play') so the class can be removed and then applied

CSS

```
@keyframes play60 {
        0% {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        100% {
            background-position: -38400px 0px;
        }
    }
    .shapeshifter {
        animation-duration: 1000ms;
        animation-timing-function: steps(60);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        width: 640px;
        height: 640px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .shapeshifter.play {
        animation-name: play60;
    }
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('shape').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    document.getElementById('shape').classList.remove('play')
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('shape').classList.add('play');
    }, 1)
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="shapeshifter " id="shape" style="background-image: url(shape.svg)"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution! I used a similar approach with setting a 1ms timeout, but instead of adding and removing a class, I toggled the animation-name from "bounce" to "none". After 1ms, the script adds back the animation-name and the animation plays again from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Use a random key in the url for cache busting.
Though your example does not have a long animation to properly test it, I have added repeatition of loading the image to make the difference noticable.

`url + "&" + Math.random()`

**No reload demo with constant URL**: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBLr/8/

**Reload demo with random URL src**: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBLr/9/

Comment: In 2020, the `&` seems to break the image link in Chrome and FF. Using `#` or `?` instead seems to work.

Comment: Probably need to escape it to "&amp"