# Restart SVG Animation on Hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have some SVG animation that looks like this:

```
<a id= "logo_hover" href="http://mywebsite.com/"><svg class="enlivenem" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 262 90" enable-background="new 0 0 262 90" xml:space="preserve" data-global-elvn="enableViewport, disableClick, none, startVisible, responsive, 500, notLoop, 500">
<g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M118.4,21.5c0,5.4-3.5,10.5-10.3,10.5c-6.9,0-10.3-5.2-10.3-10.6c0-5.5,3.4-10.5,10.3-10.5
        C115,11,118.4,16,118.4,21.5z M99.4,21.5c0,4.6,2.9,9.1,8.7,9.1c5.8,0,8.8-4.5,8.8-9.1c0-4.7-2.9-9.1-8.8-9.1
        C102.2,12.4,99.4,16.7,99.4,21.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M120.6,11.3l13.7,16.9V11.3h1.5v20.4h-0.6l-13.8-16.9v16.9h-1.6V11.3H120.6z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M140.3,11.3v18.9h11.5v1.5h-13.1V11.3H140.3z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M152.3,31.7V11.3h1.5v20.4H152.3z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M157.4,11.3l13.7,16.9V11.3h1.5v20.4H172l-13.8-16.9v16.9h-1.6V11.3H157.4z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M177,20.7h12v1.4h-12v8h12.9v1.5h-14.4V11.3h14.1v1.5H177V20.7z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M116.6,38.8l-6.9,9.7h-0.7l-6.9-9.7v15.7h-3.3V34h3.8l6.7,9.6L116,34h3.8v20.4h-3.3V38.8z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M136.2,50.1h-11.1l-1.9,4.3h-3.5l9.2-20.4h3.6l9.2,20.4h-3.5L136.2,50.1z M130.7,37.5l-4.3,9.7h8.6
        L130.7,37.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M159.1,54.4h-3.8l-6.2-7.1h-4.3v7.1h-3.3V34c3.2,0,6.3,0,9.5,0c4.7,0,7.2,3.2,7.2,6.7
        c0,2.9-1.5,5.8-5.5,6.4l6.1,6.8L159.1,54.4z M144.8,37v7.4h6.2c2.7,0,3.9-1.7,3.9-3.6c0-1.8-1.2-3.8-3.9-3.8H144.8z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M159.6,54.4V34h3.2v20.4H159.6z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M180.8,34v12c0,5.2-3.4,8.8-8.7,8.8c-5.1,0-8.7-3.2-8.7-8.7h3.2c0,3.6,1.9,5.6,5.5,5.6
        c3.6,0,5.5-2.4,5.5-5.8V37H171v-3H180.8z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M199.8,34v12c0,6-4,9-8.9,8.8c-4.5-0.1-8.4-3.1-8.4-8.8V34h3.2v12c0,3.7,2.2,5.7,5.2,5.8
        c3.3,0.1,5.7-1.9,5.7-5.8V34H199.8z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M215.1,50.1h-11.1l-1.9,4.3h-3.5l9.2-20.4h3.6l9.2,20.4h-3.5L215.1,50.1z M209.6,37.5l-4.3,9.7h8.6
        L209.6,37.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M234.6,48.5V34h3.3v20.4h-2.5L223.8,40v14.4h-3.3V34h2.5L234.6,48.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#96BF3D" d="M254.2,50.1h-11.1l-1.9,4.3h-3.5l9.2-20.4h3.6l9.2,20.4h-3.5L254.2,50.1z M248.7,37.5l-4.3,9.7h8.6
        L248.7,37.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M106,56.7c6.9,0,10.2,5,10.4,10c0.1,5.2-3.2,10.4-10.4,10.4h-6.9V56.7H106z M100.7,58.2v17.4h5.3
        c6.1,0,8.9-4.5,8.8-8.9c-0.1-4.3-2.9-8.5-8.8-8.5H100.7z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M119.5,66.2h12v1.4h-12v8h12.9v1.5H118V56.7H132v1.5h-12.5V66.2z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M146.6,60.7c-1.5-2.4-3.9-2.8-6.2-2.8c-2.4,0-6.2,0.9-6.2,4.1c0,2.6,2.8,3.2,6.2,3.8c3.9,0.8,8,1.5,8,5.9
        c0,4.6-4.7,5.7-8.1,5.7c-3.2,0-6.8-1.3-8.4-4.4l1.4-0.7c1.3,2.5,4.5,3.7,7,3.7c2.5,0,6.5-0.7,6.5-4.3c0-3-3.3-3.7-6.7-4.4
        c-3.7-0.7-7.6-1.5-7.6-5.2c-0.1-4.3,4.4-5.7,7.8-5.7c2.9,0,5.5,0.5,7.5,3.5L146.6,60.7z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M149.9,77.2V56.7h1.5v20.4H149.9z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M170.1,60.5c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.6-2.6c-6,0-9,4.4-9,9.1c0,4.8,3.1,9,9,9c2.2,0,4.5-0.7,6.2-2.4v-5.7h-7.1
        v-1.4h8.6v7.6c-2.1,2.1-4.7,3.3-7.7,3.3c-6.9,0-10.5-4.8-10.5-10.4c0-6.4,4.3-10.6,10.5-10.6c2.7,0,5.4,1,7.5,3.1L170.1,60.5z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M173.7,56.7l13.7,16.9V56.7h1.5v20.4h-0.6l-13.8-16.9v16.9h-1.6V56.7H173.7z" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"></path>
</g>
<circle fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="44" cy="45.9" r="42.1" data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #ffffff, 2, notRandom" class="elvn-layer"/>
<g data-elvn="drawLines, 0, 2000, #97c03c, 1, notRandom" class="elvn-layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M22.5,32.9c0.2-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.4-0.9c0.2-0.6,0.2-1.5,0-2.4
        c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.6c0.2-0.6,0.1-1.5-0.1-2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.5c0.1-0.6,0-1.4-0.2-2.3c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5
        c0.1-0.6,0-1.4-0.3-2.2c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4c0-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.4-2.1c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c0-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.5-2
        c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c0-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.9c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.9c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2
        c-0.1-0.6-0.4-1.2-0.8-1.8c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4c-0.1-0.6-0.4-1.2-0.9-1.9c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6c-0.1-0.6-0.5-1.3-1-2.1
        c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9c-0.1-0.7-0.5-1.4-1.2-2.2c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.8c-0.2-0.6-0.6-1.4-1.3-2.1c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5
        c-0.2-0.6-0.7-1.2-1.3-1.8c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3C10.9,9.1,10.4,8.5,9.9,8c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.5,0.5,2c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1
        c0.1,0.9,0.4,1.6,0.7,2.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.7,0.9,2.2c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.7-0.4c0.2,1,0.6,1.7,1.1,2.2
        c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.4c0.2,0.9,0.6,1.6,1.1,2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.2c0.3,0.8,0.6,1.4,1,1.8c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1
        c0.3,0.7,0.6,1.3,1,1.7c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2-0.1c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.1,1.6c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.3,0.7,0.8,1.2,1.2,1.6
        c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c0.4,0.7,0.8,1.2,1.3,1.6c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c0.4,0.7,0.9,1.2,1.4,1.6c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0
        c0.5,0.7,1,1.2,1.6,1.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0c0.5,0.7,1.1,1.2,1.7,1.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7,0c0.6,0.7,1.2,1.2,1.9,1.5
        c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8,0c0.7,0.7,1.4,1.2,2,1.4C21.9,32.9,22.2,32.9,22.5,32.9L22.5,32.9z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M23.1,33c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.5c0.4-0.4,0.9-1.1,1.1-1.9
        c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.3c0.4-0.4,0.8-1.1,1-1.9c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.2c0.4-0.4,0.7-1.1,0.9-1.9c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2
        c0.3-0.5,0.6-1.1,0.7-1.8c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2c0.3-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.6-1.8c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2c0.3-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.5-1.8
        c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.4-1.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c0.2-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.3-1.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
        c0.2-0.5,0.3-1.1,0.2-1.8c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2c0.2-0.5,0.2-1.2,0.2-1.9c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.4c0.2-0.5,0.2-1.3,0.1-2.1
        c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.6c0.2-0.6,0.2-1.4,0.1-2.2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c0.2-0.6,0.1-1.3-0.1-2.2c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4
        c0.1-0.6,0-1.3-0.2-2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c0-0.5-0.1-1.2-0.3-1.8c-0.3,0.6-0.5,1.3-0.5,1.8c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2
        c-0.3,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.4,2c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.6-0.3,2.2c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.6c-0.3,0.9-0.3,1.6-0.2,2.2
        c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.7c-0.2,0.8-0.2,1.5-0.1,2.1c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1,0.7-0.2,1.4,0,1.9c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.3
        c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.3,0,1.8C21.1,19,21,18.9,21,18.9c-0.1,0.7,0,1.3,0.1,1.8c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c0,0.7,0,1.3,0.2,1.8
        c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.3,1.8c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.2c0,0.7,0.2,1.4,0.4,1.9c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2
        c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.4,0.5,1.9c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.5,0.7,2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c0.2,0.8,0.4,1.5,0.8,2
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3c0.2,0.9,0.5,1.6,0.9,2C22.6,32.7,22.8,32.9,23.1,33L23.1,33z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M22.8,32.5c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1c0.5,0,1-0.2,1.6-0.6
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2c0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.5-0.7C25.9,31,25.7,31,25.6,31c0.4-0.1,0.9-0.3,1.4-0.7c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1
        c0.4-0.1,0.9-0.4,1.3-0.8c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.8c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.8
        c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.1-0.9c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.5,1-0.9c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.5,1-1
        c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.6,1-1.1c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0.1c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.6,1.1-1.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1
        c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.7,1.1-1.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.1c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,1-1.3c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.7,0.9-1.3
        c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.7-1.2c-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.5-1.2,0.8c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.6-1.2,1
        c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.4c-0.6,0.4-1,0.8-1.2,1.2c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c-0.6,0.4-1,0.8-1.2,1.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6
        c-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.8-1.1,1.2c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.5c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-0.9,1.1c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.7-0.9,1.1
        c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.4,0.4-0.6,0.8-0.8,1.1c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.4,0.4-0.6,0.8-0.7,1.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2
        c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.9-0.7,1.2c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2c-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.9-0.6,1.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c-0.3,0.5-0.5,1-0.6,1.4
        c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4c-0.3,0.5-0.5,1-0.5,1.5c0-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c-0.3,0.6-0.5,1.1-0.5,1.6c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5
        c-0.3,0.6-0.4,1.2-0.4,1.7C22.7,32,22.7,32.3,22.8,32.5L22.8,32.5z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M22.3,33.4c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.3c-0.6,0.1-1.4,0.1-2.2-0.2
        c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6-0.4c-0.6,0.1-1.3,0-2.1-0.3c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3c-0.6,0-1.3-0.1-2-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.2
        c-0.6,0-1.2-0.2-1.9-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2c-0.5,0-1.2-0.2-1.8-0.6c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c-0.5-0.1-1.1-0.3-1.7-0.6
        c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c-0.5-0.1-1.1-0.3-1.7-0.7c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1c-0.5-0.1-1.1-0.4-1.6-0.8c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1
        c-0.5-0.1-1-0.4-1.6-0.9c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6-1c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.1c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.8-1.1
        c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.8-1.3c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.7,0c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.7-1.7-1.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5,0
        c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.5-1.3c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.3-1.3c0.7,0.1,1.3,0.4,1.7,0.7c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2
        c0.8,0.2,1.4,0.5,1.8,0.8c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c0.8,0.2,1.5,0.6,1.9,1C6.1,21.2,6,21,5.9,20.8c0.8,0.3,1.5,0.7,1.9,1.2
        c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8c0.8,0.3,1.4,0.7,1.7,1.2c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6c0.7,0.3,1.2,0.7,1.6,1.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4
        c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.5,1.1c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.4,1.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c0.6,0.4,1,0.8,1.3,1.2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2
        c0.6,0.4,1,0.9,1.3,1.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0.6,0.5,1,1,1.3,1.4c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0.6,0.5,1,1.1,1.2,1.6c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5
        c0.6,0.6,1,1.1,1.2,1.7c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6c0.6,0.6,1,1.2,1.1,1.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0.6,0.7,0.9,1.3,1.1,1.9
        C22.3,32.8,22.3,33.1,22.3,33.4L22.3,33.4z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M22,32.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.6c-0.3,0.4-0.8,0.7-1.4,0.9
        c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.5c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.6-1.4,0.8c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.6-1.4,0.7c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4
        c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.4,0.6c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c-0.3,0.2-0.8,0.4-1.4,0.5c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c-0.3,0.2-0.8,0.4-1.4,0.4
        c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.3-1.3,0.4c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.3-1.3,0.3c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1
        c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.2-1.4,0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.5,0.2C9,36.1,9.1,36,9.3,35.8c-0.4,0.2-1,0.2-1.6,0.2
        c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.4c-0.4,0.2-1,0.2-1.7,0.1c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.4c-0.4,0.1-1,0.2-1.7,0c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.2
        c-0.4,0.1-1,0.1-1.6-0.1C3.9,35,4,35,4,34.9c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.4-0.2c0.5-0.3,0.9-0.4,1.4-0.4c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1
        c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.4,1.5-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c0.6-0.3,1.2-0.3,1.7-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.2-0.3,1.7-0.2
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c0.6-0.2,1.2-0.2,1.6-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3C9.1,32,9.6,32,10,32.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2
        c0.5-0.1,1-0.1,1.4,0c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0.5-0.1,1-0.1,1.4,0c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c0.5-0.1,1,0,1.4,0.1c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1
        c0.5,0,1,0,1.4,0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.5,0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2c0.6,0,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.3
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4c0.6,0.1,1.2,0.3,1.6,0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5
        c0.7,0.1,1.2,0.3,1.6,0.6C21.7,32.5,21.9,32.7,22,32.9L22,32.9z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M21.9,32.6c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.2
        c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c0,0.3-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3
        c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.7-0.5,1c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,1c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.9c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1
        c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.8c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.8c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.8c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2
        c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.8,0.8c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.6-0.9,0.8c0-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5c-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.6-1,0.9
        c0-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.4c-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.6-1,0.8c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.5-1,0.7c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1
        c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.6c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.6-0.9c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.7-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
        c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.8,0.8-0.9c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0.1c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.8,0.9-0.9c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.7,0.9-0.8
        c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.8-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.8-0.7c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.8-0.6
        c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.9-0.6c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.9-0.6c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.4,1-0.5
        c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.4,1-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.1-0.4c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1
        c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.4c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c0.5-0.2,0.9-0.4,1.2-0.4C21.5,32.5,21.7,32.5,21.9,32.6L21.9,32.6z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#96BF3D" d="M59.2,28.4c-4.9,0-9.3,1.8-12.2,7.1c-2.2-5.3-6.6-7.1-11.2-7.1
        c-1.3,0-2.6,0.2-3.9,0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.2c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1,0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
        c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.4c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.4c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2
        c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1,0.5c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1,0.6c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1l-0.1-1.3
        h-6.9v35.6h7.4V45c0-5.3,3.4-9.7,8.6-9.7c5.3,0,8.3,4.4,8.3,9.7v19.7h7.5V45c0-5.3,3.4-9.6,8.7-9.6c5.2,0,7.9,4.2,7.9,9.5v19.8h7.5
        V44.9C74.2,34.5,69,28.4,59.2,28.4z"></path>
</g>
</svg></a>'
```

it is added with PHP when the page loads. I want to restart this animation when I hover over the element.

I have tried using jQuery with AJAX, removing and readding the HTML, but that doesn't work. I have also tried using the `beginElement` method, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i would try somthing with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177571/restart-background-svg-animation?rq=1

Comment: Snap.svg has a really great SVG animation system, you should consider use it: http://snapsvg.io/