# CSS background SVG with animation only plays once

Tags: css, less

I have a button that toggles between two states, with an inline SVG for each state. Both of these SVGs have an `animate`. The first time around, the animation plays just fine. However, when toggling between states again, the animation does not play. I assume this is because of cache, but I'm not entirely sure.

I should also note that I am making a UserCSS theme for a website, and want to stick away from JavaScript, if possible.

Comment: I met the same issue, no solution still yet?

Comment: i took this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/21394901/8175165. I use react function component so the code looks like this:
`{isSuccess && <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/img/success.svg"></object>}`

Comment: @WayneMao Good that that works for you, but as I stated in the OP, I'd like to stay away from using JS. Unfortunately, it looks like that might not be possible...

Comment: that solution doesn't use JS, it use <object />

Comment: @WayneMao Regardless, it uses something that isn't CSS, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` for repeat the animation.

Comment: I'm not using CSS animations... it's using an SVG `animate` element. Besides, even if I make that repeat infinitely, it will just play the animation over and over, instead of when you toggle the button.

Comment: If you use ```animate``` element you can use ```repeatCount``` attribute . For example ```repeatCount:indefinite``` or ```repeatCount:5```

Comment: This has the issue I mentioned above. The animation will play over and over again rather than once every time you toggle.

Comment: Maybe this link useful for you. It mentions toggling svg with animate without any script https://codepen.io/mikemjharris/post/svg-toggling

Comment: The SVG already has an `animate` tag. The issue is that it will only ever play once due to what I assume is cache. Making it repeat indefinitely does not fix the issue, either.